# extjs 4 grid is not displayed correctly the first time it loads

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4

I have the following problem. i have a grid with a custom row height wich is set with css.

my css:

```
.blubb>td {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 3px 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 27px !important;
}
```

in getRow class i assign this class to the rows. This works really well the second time i load the grid. When i load the grid for the first time, it looks like this:

[image]

So it looks like the Css rules won't get applied to the rows, but why are they applied when i load the grid for the second time? You should also know, that the first 4 columns are locked, so this is a locked grid. Could someone please help me to fix this issue? Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using the `getRow`, you can use the `tdCls` property in your `Ext.grid.column.Column` [see here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-tdCls), or you can define a custom column:

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.StyleColumn', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.column.Column',
    alias: 'widget.stylecolumn',
    /* author: Alexander Berg, Hungary */

    defaultRenderer: function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
        var column = view.getGridColumns()[colIndex];
        //we can use different classes in each cell
        if (record.data.tdCls) {
            metadata.tdCls = record.data.tdCls;
        //we can use different classes in each column
        } else if (column.tdCls) {
            metadata.tdCls = record.data.tdCls;
        //we can use different classes in each grid (you can define it in viewConfig)
        } else if (view.rowCls) {
            metadata.tdCls = view.rowCls;
        //we can add a default class
        } else {
            metadata.tdCls = 'mydefault';
        }       
        return value;
    }
});
```